# Easy way to find int solutions of a function?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

While working on a problem, i transformed a function into the following form: $$y=\frac{26+17x}{17-2x}$$
Is there an efficient way to find the positive integer solutions of this problem if the numbers in the function get bigger?

Answer (score 2):

You want $\frac{26+17x}{17-2x}$ to be an integer, for some integer $x$. General idea is that for sufficiently large $|x|$ you will have $-9<\frac{26+17x}{17-2x}<-8$. So just solve this system of inequalities, get boundaries for $x$ and check them

Answer (score 0):

As $17-2x$ idd

$$(17-2x)\mid(26+17x)\iff(17-2x)\mid2(26+17x)$$

$$2y=\dfrac{2(26+17x)}{17-2x}=\dfrac{52+289}{17-2x}-17$$

$\implies17-2x$ must divide $52+289=11\cdot31$

$\implies17-2x$ must lie in $\in[\pm1,\pm11,\pm31,\pm341]$

But $y>0\implies(17x+26)(2x-17)<0\implies-\dfrac{26}{17}<x<\dfrac{17}2<9$

As $x$ is an integer, $-\dfrac{26}{17}> -2,-1\le x\le8$

Comment: $$-1\le x\le8\implies 2\ge-2x\ge-16\iff19\ge17-2x\ge1$$